# Adding dates in JavaScript in one line

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I'm trying to perform date manipulations using JavaScript on a single line, and I'm having problems with the year (not the month or day). I got the idea from this [link](http://ubshreenath.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6447FDAF06658642!508.entry). Am I missing something?

The code is as follows:

```
var newyear = new Date((new Date()).getYear(), (new Date()).getMonth(), (new Date()).getDate()+5).getFullYear();
document.write(newyear);
```

This gives me "110".

I'm not sure why?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is `newyear` only 5 days after now?

Comment: Oddly, works in IE 7, yielding "2010". Haven't bothered to test in other browsers.

Comment: @jball: Yeah. IE is always the one that stands out.

Comment: A little testing shows that IE treats both `getYear()` and `getFullYear()` identically. More reasons not to use deprecated functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(new Date()).getYear()
```

You should use `getFullYear()` here. [`getYear()` in JS means (year − 1900)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/why-does-javascript-getyear-return-108).

Answer (score 1):

```
var newyear = new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), (new Date()).getMonth(), (new Date()).getDate()+5).getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Y2K bug aside, this is a simpler expression:

```
var newyear = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+5)).getFullYear()
```

Date objects are relatively expensive and you can do this with a single Date object and less code if you don't assume it has to be a single expression.

```
var d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate()+5); var newyear = d.getFullYear()
```