# javascript date and year

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var currentDateTime = new Date();
        var oneYear = new Date();
        oneYear.setYear(oneYear.getYear() + 1);
        alert(currentDateTime + "_" + oneYear);
    });
</script>
```

i would expect the alert to output the current datetime and the datetime of one year from now. However I get this in the alert: "Fri Oct 22 2010 14:17:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)_Thu Oct 22 **0111** 14:17:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

Clearly it's not adding "1" to the Year correctly!

Whats going on? How did it become the year 0111???

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [ *Why does Javascript getYear() return 108?* ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/why-does-javascript-getyear-return-108)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is correct. [`.getYear()` returns "actual year − 1900"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear). 2010 − 1900 = 110.

[Use `.getFullYear()` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear). `.getYear()` has been deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Y2K was 10 years ago, but you're still using getYear instead of getFullYear?  tsk tsk...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.getYear()` try `.getFullYear()`