# jquery object issue with ie9 and opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datejs

I have been trying to get a script to work on my site and it works on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, but not on IE 9 (it will work in compatability mode) or Opera. Is there an issue that I'm not catching?

Here is the Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('/storage/xml/biblereading2.json', function(data) {
today = Date.today();
var name = today.getDay();
var date = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var fullday = name.toString();
var todaydoy = today.getDayOfYear();
var todaywoy = today.getWeekOfYear();
//array for months
fullmonth = new Array (12);
fullmonth[0] = "January";
fullmonth[1] = "February";
fullmonth[2] = "March";
fullmonth[3] = "April";
fullmonth[4] = "May";
fullmonth[5] = "June";
fullmonth[6] = "July";
fullmonth[7] = "August";
fullmonth[8] = "September";
fullmonth[9] = "October";
fullmonth[10] = "November";
fullmonth[11] = "December";
fullday = new Array (7);
fullday[0] = "Sunday";
fullday[1] = "Monday";
fullday[2] = "Tuesday";
fullday[3] = "Wednesday";
fullday[4] = "Thursday";
fullday[5] = "Friday";
fullday[6] = "Saturday";
var s = todaydoy - 1;
$("#biblereading").append('<p><span class="bold_font">Bible Reading for Today:</span>  </br>' + fullmonth[month] + ' ' + date + ', ' + year + '</br>' + data.schedule[s].portion.reading + '</br></p>');
});
});
```

I'm using date.js to handle the date issues in the first several variables, an array to give the spelled out month and day, and I'm calling a json from the same server.

Opera keeps telling me that I have a TypeError at data.schedule[s]

and IE 9 keeps telling me that I have an undefined or null value at data.schedule[s].

Any Ideas? (you can see this attempt at implementation [http://rosemontbaptist.com](http://rosemontbpaptist.com/) on the front page.

Comment: Do you have any `console.log()` in your scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log what todaydoy is

```
var todaydoy = today.getDayOfYear();
```

You will see it is returning the wrong value in IE, the following is copied from the watch window in IE9's console.

```
todaydoy    694324  Number
```

You need to figure out if their is bugs in the Date library you are using.

Comment: The problem after referencing the date.js library is in the way IE9 approaches the `getFullYear` function. Apparently the return on that for Firefox, Chrome, and Safari is "2012" but the return for IE9 and Opera is "112" see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763107/javascript-date-getyear-returns-different-result-between-ie-and-firefox-how-t). Thanks for your help @epascarello!