# How can I turn this date type into a normal date type ? javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I turn this `Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` into just this `2014-02-21` using javascript ?

Comment: Break it into bits (split might help) then format them into what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript - dupe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to delete this since the OP chose it as the answer (OP please choose Xotic750's) answer.

[See Xotic750's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21791408/194940)

Comment: You'll need to pad the month and day too :)

Comment: @Archer that is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: And if you are lucky enough to have an environment that parses that string correctly.

Comment: Parsing non–standard date strings is entirely implementation dependent, far better to manually parse the string. There is a *getFullYear* method that returns the full year.

Comment: note: data from another timezone will get converted to the locale.

Comment: Why `year = d.getYear() + 1900` instead of `year = d.getFullYear()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/why-does-javascript-getyear-return-108

Comment: Does anyone still use browsers today that don't support `getFullYear()`?

Comment: And if you are, then do you really expect them to successfully parse the string? :)

Comment: -1. The poster has had plenty of time to update the post, but it gets a down vote because of dependence on non–standard parsing, may cause a change of date due to time zone differences, use of *getYear* and does not correctly format 2 digit values.

Answer (score 2):

You can break the string into its parts, then format the bits into what you need:

```
// Reformat string like: Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
// do yyyy-mm-dd
function reformatDateString(s) {
    function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
    var months = {jan:'01', feb:'02', mar:'03', apr:'04', may:'05', jun:'06',
                  jul:'07', aug:'08', sep:'09', oct:'10', nov:'11', dec:'12'};
    s = s.split(/[ :]/g);
    return s[3] + '-' + months[s[1].toLowerCase()] + '-' + z(s[2]);
}
```

You can use the Date constructor, but it's not necessary here. Using the constructor to parse strings is problematic since the string in the OP doesn't fit the format specified in ES5 (which is not supported by all browsers in use) and parsing is otherwise implementation dependent.

So to use Date you need to parse the parts anyway, resulting in many extra function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard string/array manipulation

```
var timeStamp = 'Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)',
    months = {
        Jan: 1,
        Feb: 2,
        Mar: 3,
        Apr: 4,
        May: 5,
        Jun: 6,
        Jul: 7,
        Aug: 8,
        Sep: 9,
        Oct: 10,
        Nov: 11,
        Dec: 12
    },
    parts = timeStamp.split(' ', 4).slice(1),
    myStamp;

function pad(val) {
    if (val < 10) {
        val = '0' + val;
    }

    return val;
}

parts[0] = months[parts[0]];
parts.unshift(parts.pop());
parts[1] = pad(parts[1]);
parts[2] = pad(parts[2]);
mystamp = parts.join('-');
console.log(mystamp);
```

Output

```
2014-02-21
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/86qVt/)

Comment: Convoluted and a bit verbose, but it gets the job done. :-)

Comment: @RobG It's `-vv` mode. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The date `Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800` is in standard [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) format so you can create a new date using `new Date()` passing it as a parameter. This will convert it into UTC (milliseconds since 1/1/1970) which you can manipulate.

You can then convert UTC into [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) extended format (`2014-02-21T00:00:00.000Z`) with the `toISOString()` method and get the text before the `T`:

```
var utcDate = new Date('Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800');
var isoExtendedDate = utcDate.toISOString();   
var isoSimpleDate = isoExtendedDate.split("T")[0];
```

Comment: ES5 does not require implementations to support any format other than a version of ISO 8601. Parsing of other formats is implementation dependent