# jquery ui datepicker return weird year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Im iterating everydate on my datepicker, 
and it seems really odd, but it returns "115" when I try to get the current year.

does it mean 2015 ?
why the "1" ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you are using.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/why-does-javascript-getyear-return-108).

Comment: Sounds like the year *since 1900*, but without seeing your code, it is impossible to say so authoritatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get they `year` using `getFullYear()`. I guess you must be using `getYear()`.