# How is Date.prototype.getUTCFullYear() compliant with year-2000?

Tags: javascript, date

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear:

> The value returned by `getUTCFullYear()` is an absolute number that is compliant with year-2000, for example, 1995.

What does it mean to be "compliant with year-2000"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/98162/1823841

Answer (score 1):

```
The value returned by getUTCFullYear() is an absolute number that is compliant with year-2000, for example, 1995.
```

This sentence mean that the number must be positive, other than 0 and it must be write for inter(compliant with year-2000, for example 1998,1999,2000, NO 98,99,00)

Answer (score 0):

I think "compliant with year-2000" simply means that it doesn't cause issues due to the "Y2K bug."

Simply, it means that it returns a four-digit number, not a two-digit number, so that there's no ambiguity between years in different centuries.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "*compliant with year-2000*" is a bit misleading, and probably should be removed.

Initially, ECMAScript was implemented with a Java-like method called [*getYear*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getyear) which returned a 2 digit year that was the full year - 1900, so 1995 was returned as 95, 2017 as 117 and 1832 as -68. This method has now been moved to an [appendix of *ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getyear) for web browsers only and is maintained for backward compatibility reasons, it should not be used in new code.

Although the *getYear* method seems a bit weird now, it was easily converted to a full year by adding 1900.

The "Y2K" issue is that 2 digit years became an issue after 1 Jan 2000 as a date like 1/1/00 would be interpreted as 1/1/1900 when 1/1/2000 was intended (and so on for any 2 digit year). This issue persists, since `new Date(0,0,1)` creates a date for 1/1/1900, not 1/1/0000.

That is the real year 2000 (Y2K) issue, not getting the year.

To create a date between -99 and +99, you need to set the full year, e.g. for 1 Jan 23 you need to do:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(23,0,1);
```

In regard to [*getFullYear*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getfullyear) (and *getUTCFullYear*), it returns the full year, which can be any year that is roughly ±285,616 from 1970. It doesn't, of itself, avoid the Y2K issue. But it will return the actual year:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(23, 0, 1);
console.log(d.getYear());     // -1877
console.log(d.getFullYear()); // 23
```